# How to implement the default deserialiazation of a Rust Enum in custom deserialization

Tags: rust, serde

I am a new learner of Rust and currently slowly moving a Python project to Rust.
To store data between two runs of the software, I serialized my data in YAML. But I'm currently stuck on the deserialization of old file produced by Python.

One of my type is defined as following in Rust

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Symbol {
    #[serde(alias = "BOW")]
    Bow,
    #[serde(alias = "SWORD")]
    Sword,
    Poison(u8),
    // Many more variant
}
```

So far, it's work pretty well with serializing and deserializing when using files generated by Rust.

Sadly, when I chose the serialization way in Python, I serialized the poison in the shape `Poison(X)`, so to handle this, I need to implement a custom deserialization method.
For reference, the same data in YAML serialized by Rust and by Python

```yaml
# With Rust
symbols:
  - Bow
  - Poison: 10
```

```yaml
# With Python
symbols:
  - BOW
  - POISON(10)
```

I want my Rust program to be able to read files output by Python as well as the ones output by Rust; people use this program and I don't want to break backward compatibility (but I don't have forward-compatibility).

So, I started to write my custom deserialization and used to OOP in Python, I would want my deserialization to inherit the default behavior.
But Rust does not provide OOP, so I would have to write a code to mimic the default deserialization. And I don't want to do this part, as I am pretty sure, serde's developers made it way better than I would.

So, I'm asking you if you would happen to have an idea of how to do it without re-coding the default behavior.

Comment: Can you add an example YAML file produced by Python and the equivalent for Rust.

Comment: @cafce25 Indeed I should have added them, it is now done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement this. The easiest IMHO is to deserialize the struct as normal, and fall back in case of a string.

Like the following:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Symbol {
    #[serde(alias = "BOW")]
    Bow,
    #[serde(alias = "SWORD")]
    Sword,
    Poison(u8),
    // Many more variant
}

#[derive(Serialize, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
#[serde(transparent)]
pub struct SymbolWrapper(pub Symbol);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for SymbolWrapper {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        #[serde(untagged)]
        enum Format {
            New(Symbol),
            Old(String),
        }

        let data = Format::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        match data {
            Format::New(symbol) => Ok(SymbolWrapper(symbol)),
            Format::Old(description) => {
                let Some(description) = description.strip_suffix(")") else {
                    return Err(serde::de::Error::custom("expected `name(...)`"));
                };
                let Some((variant, data)) = description.split_once('(') else {
                    return Err(serde::de::Error::custom("expected `name(...)`"));
                };
                match variant {
                    "POISON" => Ok(SymbolWrapper(Symbol::Poison(
                        data.parse::<u8>().map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)?,
                    ))),
                    _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom(format!(
                        "expected a known name, found `{variant}`"
                    ))),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=54e222c8742d5c81b7080354821da26d).

Instead of `SymbolWrapper`, you can use `Symbol` directly and have the custom deserialization logic everywhere it is a field with `#[serde(deserialize_with = "...")]`.